# awt frame and color dispose - how

Tags: java, colors, awt, frame, dispose

What is the correct way to dispose a frame and colors?
I have an awt frame that is being created on a composite. 
I have listener for when the parent is closed it should call dispose() method.

This method makes the frame close.

```
public void dispose() {
    if (frame != null) {
        // frame.dispose()
        frame = null;
    }
}
```

However, if I uncomment frame.dispose() the frame never closes.
Is calling dispose needed?

Also, for colors - is it okay to just set them as null?

Comment: I think its done by garbage collector. Then what is the purpose of the dispose methods?

Comment: anyone has any idea?